# Why don't ATMs show blank arrows for unused buttons?

Tags: usability, navigation, buttons, layout, physical

Have you ever had trouble lining the arrows up with the correct button on ATM consoles and other similar interfaces?  Height of user can affect perceived alignment, as well as poor installation or maintenance.

So why not just add some blank arrows (or some other tic or blank object) to help quickly see how many buttons down I need to go?

```
      +---------------------------------+
      |                                 |   
      |   How much money do you want?   |
      |                                 |   
      |                                 |   
      |                                 |   
+--+  |                                 |  +--+
|  |  |                                 |  |  |
+--+  |                                 |  +--+
      |                         $5 ---> |   
+--+  |                                 |  +--+
|  |  |                                 |  |  |
+--+  |                                 |  +--+
      |          1 million dollars ---> |   
+--+  |                                 |  +--+
|  |  |                                 |  |  |
+--+  |                                 |  +--+
      |                                 |   
+--+  |                                 |  +--+
|  |  |                                 |  |  |
+--+  |                                 |  +--+
      +---------------------------------+
```

versus

```
      +---------------------------------+
      |                                 |   
      |   How much money do you want?   |
      |                                 |   
      |                                 |   
      | <                             > |   
+--+  |                                 |  +--+
|  |  |                                 |  |  |
+--+  |                                 |  +--+
      | <                       $5 ---> |   
+--+  |                                 |  +--+
|  |  |                                 |  |  |
+--+  |                                 |  +--+
      | <        1 million dollars ---> |   
+--+  |                                 |  +--+
|  |  |                                 |  |  |
+--+  |                                 |  +--+
      | <                             > |   
+--+  |                                 |  +--+
|  |  |                                 |  |  |
+--+  |                                 |  +--+
      +---------------------------------+
```

I've been cursing ATM programmers for decades over this guess-the-button game when it seems easily avoidable to me.  Perhaps someone has some test data that shows this would be bad for some reason.

Comment: Banks still relying heavily on COBOL-backed IBM mainframes demonstrates where their priorities are.

Comment: Found this great photo illustrating the point.  Two more tic marks on the screen would make it so much easier to figure out which button to hit.  http://boingboing.net/2010/11/12/atm-user-interface-f.html

Comment: This would help, but feels like a band-aid rather than fixing that actual UX issue (alignment)

Comment: @juanitogan [This is the image I often refer to](http://i.imgur.com/E8Io38h.jpg) when describing how parallax error affects touch-screen interfaces.

Comment: I have seen this being done (although not with arrows but empty "button labels"). Also the alignment issue is on old ATMs mostly due to different height of people, thus different view angles. I have less problems with this than my wife.

Comment: I've seen blank arrow buttons on old ATM's, and I've seen plenty of touch screens that yet still have buttons and are nicely aligned. I believe the buttons today are a result of accessibility requirements (visually impaired). While it has taken a while for color, touch-screen ATMs to appear in the US, it has happened, and the situation appears to improve every year.

Comment: Given the images in the comments, this seems to be an issue with some peoples' depth perception and/or spatial memory...?  I have no difficulties seeing which arrows align with which buttons, even in the angled pictures.  (I'm not saying it's not an issue, but that it might be a common edge case like color blindness - until seeing those pictures, I thought the question was talking about arrows that were actually mis-aligned (like the miscalibrated touchscreen on a nearby ATM I use, for a good week the touch-area was an inch to the left))

Comment: re: [on hold] Perhaps this question is too provocative and gathers too many opinions. On the other hand, I really would like to know the answer to see if I'm missing some important rule in my own design work. Given that the usefulness of such disabled markers is apparent, even obvious, I figure the engineers must have had some reason for leaving them out. I want to know what that reason is. Sure, I could try to explain all this in the question but how many read long questions? Look for and read all my comments here.

Comment: @juanitogan I'd be extremely surprised if this was the decision of any engineer (as opposed to a visual designer).

Comment: One of the ATM in IAD lets you to type numbers corresponding to the options from the number pad. The options on the screen were not numbered and I tried several times counting left-right, top-bottom, vice versa and got my options wrong all the time.

Answer (score 10):

ATM software is generally written by the bank, whereas ATM hardware comes from a very limited set of manufacturers like NCR.

As ATM hardware improves, the same software is deployed on many different device form factors often at once; some are old-school (like the ones you refer to in the question) with the buttons running down each side of the screen, and modern ones are touch screens.

That's why most ATM software looks like it's designed for touch even though most ATMs seem to be the old ones.

And that leads us to the question you asked: your little blank notches wouldn't correspond to anything on a touch screen.

The *solution*, then, of course, is to stop designing the software once for both device form factors. The reason that doesn't happen is mostly that ATM software needs expensive validation to confirm it's financially secure.

And sadly I doubt many users change banking providers on the strength of their ATM UX.

Comment: OTOH, I think ATM UX is a potentially HUGE basis for a choice of bank -- especially the new(ish) feature some banks have where you get a scan of your checks (and possibly even instant access to the funds) when you deposit them, rather than having to trust that they make it to the right place.

Comment: @R.. I hope you're right (and I know in the US [Wells Fargo have pushed hard to differentiate on UX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NI1Rpc5bUI) and [they had previously commissioned Pentagram to produce a great ATM design](http://www.pentagram.com/work/#/all/finance/newest/2597/)), but how many people get a chance to play with ATM software before choosing a financial institution?

Comment: who'd ever change bank based on their ATM screens? 90% of the ATMs I use are NOT from my own bank, and that's the case for a lot of people. I use the nearest ATM when I need cash, don't go looking for one from my own bank which may be in the next town over (or the next country over...). And as most banks use the same ATM models anyway it hardly matters.

Comment: @jwenting - I love my bank because of its modern user interface; it keeps me loyal and is consistent across its ATMs (which are everywhere here), mobile app and website (and in Australia a lot of people will use their banks ATMs to avoid $2 fees).

Comment: @misterManSam here in the Netherlands there's no fee for using the ATMs of other banks so the situation is different (except for those mobile ones they put in stores and events, and then you pay like 10% fee irrespective of whether it's your bank or not). Also I've never seen an ATM here with a touch screen, only a few abroad and there of course you pay always. ATMs here are everywhere, but usually there's not many different one. Especially in rural areas one town may have bank A represented, the next one over bank B, etc.

Comment: @jwenting - Of course, everywhere is different. When I am living in the UK it is the same as you, free ATMs everywhere. Point is, depending on where you are (Australia for instance), you might choose a bank over something as simple as its ATM UI :)

Comment: Interesting insight but I'm not convinced the touchscreen argument answers the question. This question goes way back to the 1960s when I doubt touchscreens were relevant in the UI design. Even if they were, disabled options (blank or grayed) on touchscreens are not confounding. My phone uses grayed objects and, as far as I know, people don't spend all day punching at them out of frustration. -- Okay, _maybe_ the banks had no choice but the firmware engineers were hopefully creative enough to consider these things. So why did they pass on it? The usefulness of blank arrows is not that elusive.

Comment: @juanitogan As a tall guy who's often affected by parallax error on touch screens, I'm certainly with you that this is a problem worth solving (doubly so because most of my design work is on touch screens). I don't think disabled buttons are an acceptable solution on a touch screen like this, though. The visual design of an ATM is all about simplicity; adding any other large visual element is going to come at the cost of that. The logical solution to me is to [run a line all the way from the button to the on-screen button](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UsFrk.jpg) so parallax isn't a factor.

Comment: @KitGrose You are still too modern. Yes, LCDs are reliable on alignment. The old CRTs had zoom and alignment issues. Further, a UI designed for one bezel may not align well with bezels on new machines with the same software. I agree with simplicity and reducing objects but I'm also surprised at how many engineers (designers) cannot see the value of disabled/placeholder objects even though great designs use them (such objects hint there is more to consider). Still, I wonder if past ATM engineers found even a simple > or hollow ► to be too distracting somehow--or if someone failed to try it.

Comment: @KitGrose Regarding rich UIs, I test all sorts of ideas. Grayed, hidden, collapsing, whatever. In general, I find that in interfaces that mostly stay the same, while changing state, that it is better to gray out than jump things around. With something like an ATM or gas pump, I may not render a rich gray button but I might leave a light shadow or a frame (depending on contrast requirements for the visually impaired), or maybe just use negative space differently (probably the best idea here). Many possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

Buttons down the edge are old technology and  I suspect they'll all be replaced by touch screens before too long and this problem will go away.

Comment: My bank already has, quite a while ago, in fact.

Comment: ATM machines are expensive as hell. Until they break down you won't see touch screen stuff for a while, especially in 3rd world countries

Comment: why would a bank replace a perfectly fine ATM just to get a fancy touch screen that requires more maintenance and breaks more often when they have hundreds or thousands of ATMs already that are robust, safe, and function just fine? The replacement cost (and installation cost) would be horrendous for very little gain.

Comment: Even if this is true (and I'm not convinced it is), this is in no way whatsoever an answer to the question. At best it should be a comment.

Comment: I think it *is* an answer. For anyone contemplating building a user interface with a screen surrounded by buttons: don't! Use a touch screen instead.

Comment: @Colin'tHart when those ATMs were designed touch screens were even more fragile and expensive than they are now, and much more unreliable. They were utterly inappropriate for something like an ATM.

Comment: @Colin'tHart Touchscreens can be far worse than buttons.  An ATM that I use regularly was at one point miscalibrated for about a week.  The whole thing was off by a good inch or so, putting touch-area for $100 on top of the displayed button for $20 (as well as all the other options in that column).

Comment: What happens when miscreants damage the screen as sewms to be the case in the uk a lot of the time.  At least with physical buttons its a bit easier to make vandal resistant.

Comment: It would be interesting to get some data on the strength of the glass used in ATM CRT displays versus one using say Gorrilla Glass.